# Array with `n` elements in Kotlin doesn't work

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I thought it was really simple...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = Array<Boolean>(5) { false };
}
```

But apparently, that doesn't work (it gives a NullPointerException): [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM08jsSi92ErBsagosdImuKQoMy/dTlOhmouzLDFHIVHBFirjlJ@fk5qYZ6dhCpRUSEvMKU5VqLXmqv3/HwA)

This is the right way to do it according to another SO post that the OP commented was correct, so is it the runtime environment's fault or is Kotlin behaving weirdly?

Comment: It works. Try it on the official Kotlin Playground: https://play.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: @gpunto that's weird. well I guess TIO's just broken...

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: @crgarridos Thanks, but it's been fixed now. Turns out it was a known bug that was fixed after TIO updated Kotlin to the most recent version.

Answer (score 2):

For me it results in `[false, false, false, false, false]`:

```
val a = Array(5) { false }
println(a.contentToString())
```

Seems to be an issue related to the environment you were using.